# Algebraic data type - rewrite system

Tags: fl.formal-languages

Let's define the integer ADT.

It has, as generators, the constant 0 (a generator) and the succ operation.
Moreover, it also contains the add operation defined by the (usual) axioms

> add (0, x) = x (where x is a variable of type integer)
>   add (succ(x), y) = succ(add(x,y)).

Let's assume that I have two terms: `add(x, succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))` and `succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))))`.

Is there an algorithm that finds all the substitutions allowing the first term to be rewritten to the second term?

Thanks in advance,
Ayroles

Answer (score 9):

You could encode these into Horn Clauses (= Prolog) and use [resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29) (= Prolog's implementation technique).

More explicitly, your Prolog code file will look like the following:

```
add( 0,    N, N ).
add( succ(N), M, succ(Sum) ) :- add( N, M, Sum ).
```

Asking the following query at the command prompt in a prolog interpreter will give you an answer for X:

```
add( X, succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))), succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))))).
```

Which is:

```
X = succ(succ(0)) .
```

Using tracing within the Prolog interpreter will give you the series of substitutions used.

Fill all the gaps in yourself, and you will learn a lot.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question is yes. Unification modulo an ACU (associative, commutative, unital) operator is decidable. See Baader and Snyder's chapter ["Unification Theory"](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~snyder/publications/UnifChapter.pdf) in the Handbook of Automated Reasoning.